# Project not getting imported in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

First of all I am sorry guys ,if in case this question is a duplicate.
But I am not able to frame this problem to search in forums and search engines. Hence i am asking this..
**Here is question**
I am facing an unusual problem while importing an already existing **Android project** in Eclipse. **when i click on finish , nothing happens.**
What may be the issue?

Comment: I cant attach any snapshots bcoz I dnt have reputation 10.

Comment: My SDK is fully updated

Comment: What is "nothing happens"? Does the new project wizard stay there? Does it go away, but no project is added? What are your inputs to the wizard? More detail, please.

Comment: @Geobits : yes the new project wizard stays there

Comment: @Geobits: new project wizard stays right there

Comment: @Geobits: nothing happens on clicking "finish"

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues trying to use the import existing projects in Eclipse.  It is better to use the "Existing Android Code into workspace" option.

Select the file menu, select import, select the Android folder, select "Existing Android Code into Workspace" option.

Comment: #wyoskibum: I have followed the steps mentioned by you.. but still nothing happens on clicking "finish"

Comment: Can you create a new project in the workspace?  At this point I might consider removing and re-installing Eclipse.